# Interface Props undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, prisma

I am working on a project with Next.js, Typescript, and Prisma. I am new to all so I am building a simple TODO app. I am currently trying to implement the ability to filter a TODO card by priority (High, Medium, Low). I am trying to use interface to break down the Priority model I have in Prisma. The way I have seen it broken down is like this:
`interface Props { searchParams: { priority: Priority }; };`

When I pass props through the component it seems like searchParams is undefined all the way through. I get the following error:

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'priority')

Source
app/todos/_components/TodoCard.tsx (19:52) @ priority

17 | const priorities = Object.values(Priority);
18 | // console.log(priorities);

> 19 | const priority = priorities.includes(searchParams.priority)

I am not sure how to get past this and pull out the individual value I need from Priority. Any advice would be helpful! This is my code:

```
import prisma from "@/prisma/client";
import { Card, Separator, Text } from "@radix-ui/themes";
import { FiTrash2 } from "react-icons/fi";
import { BiEditAlt } from "react-icons/bi";
import TodoActions from "./TodoActions";
import TodoPriorityBadge from "./TodoPriorityBadge";
import { Priority } from "@prisma/client";


interface Props {
  searchParams: { priority: Priority };
};

const TodoCard = async ({ searchParams }: Props) => {
  // console.log(searchParams.priority);

  const priorities = Object.values(Priority);
  // console.log(priorities);
  const priority = priorities.includes(searchParams.priority)
    ? searchParams.priority
    : undefined;

  const todos = await prisma.todo.findMany({
    where: {
      priority,
    },
  });

  return (
    <>
      <TodoActions></TodoActions>
      <div className="space-y-3 px-6">
        <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-6">
          {todos.map((todo) => (
            <Card key={todo.id} asChild style={{ maxWidth: 350 }}>
              <a href={`/todos/${todo.id}`}>
                <Text as="div" size="2" weight="bold">
                  {todo.title}
                </Text>
                <Separator my="3" size="3" />
                <div className="mb-2">
                  <TodoPriorityBadge priority={todo.priority} />
                </div>

                <Text as="div" color="gray" size="2">
                  Due Date: {todo.dueDate}
                </Text>
                <div className="flex space-x-3">
                  <BiEditAlt color="green" />
                  <FiTrash2 color="red" />
                </div>
              </a>
            </Card>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";

export default TodoCard;
```

This is my Prisma schema:

```
model Todo {
  id          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  title       String   @db.VarChar(255)
  description String   @db.Text
  priority    Priority @default(HIGH)
  dueDate     String
  createdAt   DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime @updatedAt
}

enum Priority {
  HIGH
  MEDIUM
  LOW
}
```

Comment: _"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'priority')"_ This error message means that the variable that you are accessing the `priority` property on is `undefined`. That means that `searchParams` is undefined. `searchParams` is a prop which means that `TodoCard` is not getting passed `searchParams` prop correctly. So how are calling `<TodoCard/>` and passing it `searchParams` as a prop? Your problem is mostly likely there, and not in the code you've posted.

Comment: I have my whole Todo card posted but this is how I am passing Props:

const TodoCard = async ({ searchParams }: Props) => {

Comment: That's how your component _declares_ it's props. How are you passing those props _to_ this component? For example in some other component, you probably have `<TodoCard searchParams={valueThatIsTheSearchParamsPropHere} />`. That's the code you should be looking at here.

Comment: Ok I didnt realize that was the problem. This is the updated code for the page I am calling it on 
`import TodoCard from "../app/todos/_components/TodoCard";
import { Priority } from "@prisma/client";

// This will be dashboard/home page. Display all todos here.
export default function Home() {
  const searchParams = { priority: Priority.HIGH };

  return (
    <div>
      <TodoCard searchParams={searchParams}></TodoCard>
    </div>
  );
}`
I am now getting the error Property 'priority' does not exist on type 'Props' on the TodoCard page

Comment: Exactly what line is giving you that error? It would help if you added the code from your comment to you question. You can just [edit] the question. Be sure it indicate exactly _where_ that error is in your code.